# How to use list() when in an ipdb session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipdb

In a Python 3.5.2 script where I have, e.g.,

```py
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

The interpreter hits these lines and drops me into an `ipdb` session. Understandably, `ipdb` has limited functionality compared to an iPython interpreter session (e.g., no magic commands). However, I'm surprised to find that some Python built-ins don't work, namely `list()`.

```py
ipdb> some_data                                                                                                                                               
<zip object at 0x7f416e820388>
ipdb> list(some_data)                                                                                                                                         
*** Error in argument: '(some_data)'
ipdb> list([])                                                                                                                                                
*** Error in argument: '([])'
```

I'm guessing there is a name collision between the built-in function `list()` and one of the `ipdb` commands. Any way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ipdb> somedata = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
ipdb> !list(somedata.keys())
['a', 'b']
```

`!` overrides all `pdb` commands.

Source: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/106:

Answer (score 2):

in pdb it seems you can use C like convertions. It is probably similar in iPython.

Can you try:

```
ipdb> res = (list) (some_data)
```

Comment: That's it! The space between `(list)` and `(some_data)` is not necessary. Incidentally, the same syntax works in a regular Python/ IPython session; not sure what the technical name for this is: `(list)([])`.